# JRuby / OpenSSL error when attempting to start Rails server:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

When I attempt to start my Rails server, I receive an error that reads:

`OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: setting default path failed: Invalid keystore format`

I suspect that my machine's keystore has somehow become corrupted. Does anyone know how I might go about resolving this issue?

Comment: A quick search of the interwebs suggests a fix: https://gist.github.com/kendagriff/adec3713b4dfe6a1abdf

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this and it fails because the keystore password I enter is incorrect. Not sure of how to address that